# I can't see any shader in Shader List when debugging GLSL using NSight

Tags: debugging, opengl, glsl, shader, nsight

Environment: This is the first time I using Nsight in VS2013. My GPU is GTX630M, and OS is win7 x64, version of OpenGL is 4.5, Nsight 4.6, GPU Driver 309.XX. My program using FreeGlut and glew, it is like the first program in *OpenGL Programming Guide Edition 8*, Chapter 1.

I used two shaders, one is vertex shader(**.vert**), another is fragment shader(**.frag**). As the title, after I start graphics debugging, I CAN'T see ANY shader in Shader List, but the program can running in a little stumble.

How should I do so that I can see the shader?

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: I never got NSight to work on my box. The free [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/) could be an alternative.

Comment: @random Sure, which part of code do you need? LoadShader() or GLSL?

Comment: @mathias I'll try it. ^_^

Comment: @mathias How do you debug GLSL? It seems not to contain the function to set breakpoint on glsl code.

Comment: Hi,

Seems it's duplicated [question][1] as which posted on Nvidia's developer forum, I notice it's the same nickname, ;)

Same question here, are you using laptop which has iGPU and dGPU that combine a Optimise system?

Also I notice your driver is too late for Nsight, please try to install the latest driver.

  [1]: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/824590/nsight-visual-studio-edition/i-can-t-see-any-shader-in-shader-list-when-debugging-glsl/

Comment: @YanAn As you think, It's me ^_^. Actually, I'm using laptop with iGPU and dGPU. When I launch my program, I used the dGPU (iGPU can't operate the shaders, and I set *glut* need openGL version 4.5 context ). Now, I have updated GPU driver to 347.88, but the Nsight does not work as before. I'll try to disable the Optimise, thanks.